# Insert from One MS Access database to Another MS Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, duplicates, insert-into

I have to take the data from MS Access DB to another. 
This was insert statement used

```
 cmd.CommandText = @"Insert Into [MS Access;PWD=pw;DATABASE=" + currentDBPath + @"].[Orders]  Select   *  FROM  [Orders]  where OrderDate>=#" + from.ToShortDateString() + "# and  OrderDate <=#" + to.ToShortDateString() + "# and  IsCustomer=Yes  ";
```

This statement works fine. But some one started to enter the data directly to target database and also in the source. This created duplicated records. Now I want to copy those orders from source which are not in the target DB's table.

Comment: _Someone started to enter data directly...._ Fire him/her

Comment: Great Tip! will forward to higher Authorities

Comment: Sorry, but really this is costly and whoever is the responsable should pay for it.If this is just one fix then you could temporarily import the table in the other database and use the MSAccess interface to find and fix the duplicate. If this is a recurring situation then you need to develop a full sinchronitazion procedure and, as said, it is costly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Orders table has a primary key named IDOrers, you must bring both tables to one DB, so you can compare data.
**Easy option:** have in Sours DB a link to [Orders] on Destination DB, named `OrdersDest`. In that case you create on destination a query of missing orders, named `MissingOrders` :

```
SELECT Orders.* FROM Orders LEFT JOIN OrdersDest ON OrdersDest.IDOrders = Orders.IDOrders WHERE OrdersDest.IDOrders Is Null
```

Your Command will now look like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"Insert Into [MS Access;PWD=pw;DATABASE=" + currentDBPath + @"].[Orders]  Select   *  FROM  [MissingOrders]  where OrderDate>=#" + from.ToShortDateString() + "# and  OrderDate <=#" + to.ToShortDateString() + "# and  IsCustomer=Yes ";
```

You could also pass the data through this linked table:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"Insert Into [OrdersDest]  Select * FROM [MissingOrders]  where OrderDate>=#" + from.ToShortDateString() + "# and  OrderDate <=#" + to.ToShortDateString() + "# and  IsCustomer=Yes  ";
```

Comment: @faheemkhan, Other option would be to creating two DataTables, `DSsours` and `DSdestination`, Filling them with data from Orders table in sours and destination DBs, passing relevant records from `DSsours` to DSdestination`, and adding them back to destination DB.

Comment: I didn't get why did you use Left Join. also there was little syntax issue with 1st query

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Comment: As for the left Join, you want the query to contain all orders from sours, you therefor have `orders` on the left side of a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: you want the query to contain **all** orders from sours, you therefor have `orders` on the left side of a `LEFT JOIN`, and exclude data already in destination: `WHERE OrdersDest.IDOrders Is Null`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any solution to what I was looking for in my question , So I decided to just delete the duplicated data in destination database.

I used the below statement to delete the data ,

```
   Delete * from Orders where AutoOrderID   in (SELECT Orders.AutoOrderID FROM Orders Inner JOIN OrdersSource ON OrdersSource .OrderId = Orders.OrderId and OrdersSource .OrderDate=Orders.OrderDate);
```